# How to get data from user for linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I tried to create linked list in C which will allow the user to insert data, print the list and exit from the program. I can insert the data and print the list one time but when I try to print the list again it shows list as empty. The address of the header has been changed to `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node* head;
struct Node
    {
int data;
struct Node* next;
    };
void Insert(int x)
{
    struct Node* temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}
print()
{
    printf("%d",head);
    printf("\nthe list is\n");
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",head->data);
        head=head->next;
            }
}
int main()
{
    //head=NULL;
    int n,i,x,option;
do
{
    printf("\n1.Insert 2.Print 3.Exit");
    printf("\nenter option:");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    if(option==1){
    printf("\nTotal no to be entered:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    Insert(x);
}}
else{
if(option==2){
    print();
    }
}
}while(option!=3);
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `head` to `NULL`. Otherwise, you will wander off the end of your list into oblivion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `head` is global, so it's implicitly initialized to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print` method **changes** the `head` pointer, so next time you access the list, `head` will point to `null`. You should use a different pointer for the iteration:

```
void print()
{
    Node* iter = head;
    printf("%d", iter);
    printf("\nthe list is\n");
    while(iter!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",iter->data);
        iter=iter->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lopping over the linked list with the pointer `head` to the head of your list, so at the end of the loop, `head` reaches the end of the list and nothing remains to print.

To resolve the problem you need to keep `head` on its place (the head of the list) and loop with a second pointer `loop_ptr`

```
print()
{   Node* loop_ptr = head;// create a pointer to loop with
    printf("%d",loop_ptr);
    printf("\nthe list is\n");
    while(loop_ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",loop_ptr->data);
        loop_ptr=loop_ptr->next;// at the end head points always to the head of your list
    }
}
```

Nota Bene:

```
struct Node* next;
struct Node* head;
```

This is a bad practice when dealing with pointers. Unlike other data structures, a pointer must always properly initialized to avoid [unexpected mess](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html). In your case, you can do this:

```
struct Node* next= NULL;
struct Node* head= NULL;
```